# IPasswordHasher of identity 2.0 to recover password?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

Is it possible to decrypt the password hashed by IPasswordHasher of Identity 2.0?
I see only two methods `HashPassword` and `PasswordVerificationResult`.
What if i want to decrypt the password? Is there any way around?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? There's a reason it was hashed and not encrypted (thus not "decryptable").

Comment: Just in case, if i want to administrator to let view the password in case user forget password. we have not implemented recovery password strategy yet.

Comment: If the user forgot their password then make them reset it. There are several security issues with letting them view the password they had.

Comment: Ok. any suggestion how to implement reset password in MVC 5? I am not using default identity 2.0.

Comment: Have the user enter their email in. Create a password reset token and email them a link with the token to reset their password. When they click it or after a certain time period the token expires. If they clicked it have them reset the password to something else. Research that and ask a new question if you need more help than that.

Answer (score 4):

No, we intentionally do not support "Recover password" functionality out of the box as its insecure, reset password is the mechanism that should be used instead.